# Migrated servers: Odd characters breaking database commits

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, mariadb

I am having issues with 'weird' characters breaking database commits by my system.  Characters such as Â, ©, ` are all breaking database commits.  The characters appear fine when pulled from the database, for example viewing a product.  Let's say you are viewing product data, and one of the fields has one of these characters.  You change another field, or that field.  Click update.  All data that is sent through the POST updates as blank in the database.  If I remove these odd characters, the database updates correctly from the website.

I've pursued the obvious problems, such as the PHP charset and MySQL charset for the database.  The problem is that the site works fine on my test server.

The test server uses MySql 5.5.46.  The problem server uses MariaDb 5.5.48.

PHP 5.45 is used on both.  The only diff between the php.ini files is the error reporting.

All tables use Latin1.  And, as stated, the system works fine in the test environment.  This is only an issue on the new (MariaDb) server.

What can I troubleshoot on the MariaDb installation that may be breaking on these weird characters?  I should note that, through phpmyadmin, everything works fine.  I can use these characters without issue.

Comment: Is that phpmyadmin installation on the same system that your other scripts break?

Comment: What sort of PHP code does your database insertion in this example? It sounds like you're describing an encoding mismatch. Ideally your database is UTF-8 clean, but this is not always the case. If you get form submissions, ensure they're UTF-8, a task that is not always easy.

Comment: The phpmyadmin is indeed on the same system as the breaking database commits.

Comment: The database and system use Latin1 for encoding.  This is properly set in the locale scripts for the system.  The system is a zencart base, heavily modified.  The scripts in question use the zencart abstraction class for accessing the php mysql_* functions.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'`.

Comment: character_set_client = utf8, character_set_connection = utf8,  character_set_database = latin1, character_set_filesystem = binary, character_set_results = utf8, character_set_server = latin1                     
character_set_system = utf8, character_sets_dir = /usr/share/mysql/charsets/